# CGEventTapCreate's watching keyboard input in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Greetings.
I try to make kid control application. The keyboard logger is a part of this application.
I use CGEventTapCreate to watch the keyboard. This works good, but sometimes I get duplicating key down events. They do not have [NSEvent isARepeat] set, just duplicates. For example I can type "qwerty" but application gets key down events for these characters: "qqwweerrttyy". Maybe somebody experienced smth like it? I get this problem on 10.5&10.6 (both are Intel).

I post here keyboard logger install & handler methods:

```
- (BOOL)installKeyboardLogger
{
  CGEventMask keyboardMask = CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventKeyDown);
  CGEventMask mouseMask = CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventMouseMoved) |   CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventLeftMouseDown) |
      CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventRightMouseDown);

  CGEventMask mask = keyboardMask + mouseMask;// + mouseMask;//CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventKeyDown) | CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventMouseMoved);

  // Try to create keyboard-only hook. It will fail if Assistive Devices are not set.
  mMachPortRef =  CGEventTapCreate(
                                   kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap,
                                   kCGTailAppendEventTap, // kCGHeadInsertEventTap
                                   kCGEventTapOptionListenOnly,
                                   keyboardMask,
                                   (CGEventTapCallBack)eventTapFunction,
                                   self );
  if (!mMachPortRef)
    [mLogFile logNeedAssistiveDevice: @"Can't install keyboard hook."];
  else
    CFRelease(mMachPortRef);

  mMachPortRef = CGEventTapCreate(
                                  kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap,
                                  kCGTailAppendEventTap, // kCGHeadInsertEventTap
                                  kCGEventTapOptionListenOnly,
                                  mask,
                                  (CGEventTapCallBack)eventTapFunction,
                                  self );
  if (!mMachPortRef)
  {
    [mLogFile logNeedAssistiveDevice: @"Can't install keyboard&mouse hook."];
    return NO;
  }

  mKeyboardEventSrc = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, mMachPortRef, 0);
  if ( !mKeyboardEventSrc )
    return NO;

  CFRunLoopRef runLoop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent();
  if ( !runLoop )
    return NO;

  CFRunLoopAddSource(runLoop,  mKeyboardEventSrc, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
  return YES;
}


    CGEventRef eventTapFunction(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef event, void *refcon)
{
  if (type != NX_KEYDOWN && type != NX_OMOUSEDOWN && type != NX_OMOUSEUP && type != NX_OMOUSEDRAGGED &&
      type != NX_LMOUSEUP && type != NX_LMOUSEDOWN && type != NX_RMOUSEUP && type != NX_RMOUSEDOWN &&
      type != NX_MOUSEMOVED && type != NX_LMOUSEDRAGGED && type != NX_RMOUSEDRAGGED) 
    return event;

  NSEvent* sysEvent = [NSEvent eventWithCGEvent:event];

  if (type == NX_KEYDOWN && [sysEvent type] == NSKeyDown)
  {
    if (![sysEvent isARepeat])
      [(ControlPanelController*)refcon handleCapturedCharacters: [sysEvent characters]];
  }
  else
    [(ControlPanelController*)refcon handleMouse];

  return event;
}
```

Comment: Does your app have a graphical interface that users interact with?

Comment: Yes, it is Cocoa. It does not have own icon in Dock however (agent application)

Comment: Now I have workaround - I check if the duplicating events comes faster than in 0.2 seconds.

Comment: It might be that it's getting both the KeyDown and the KeyUp events.

Comment: But it does not happen every time.

Comment: when you say it doesnt happen every time, do you mean doesnt happen every key press or doesn't happen on every run of the program?

Comment: Based on the code above you have scenarios where you are creating two event taps that have the same callback and both capture keyboard input.