# How to capture keyboard & mouse events even when the Qt app is minimized / in background / out of focus?

Tags: c++, qt, mouseevent, keypress, capture

Here the requirement is just to check if any key was pressed or any mouse click or movement has happened. Capturing other specific details is not required.
I am fine to do every 1 second polling as well to see if any mouse or key event happened.

Will `QAbstractNativeEventFilter` be of any help?
Any other platform independent C++ library also will be useful.

---

Below is a sample code to capture mouse & keyboard events *only* when the app is in focus:

```
#include<QApplication>
#include<QDebug>
#include<QKeyEvent>
#include<QWidget>

struct Widget : public QWidget
{
  Widget ()
  {
    installEventFilter(this);
    grabKeyboard();
    grabMouse();
    setMouseTracking(true);
  }
  ~Widget () { qDebug() << "~Event()"; }

  bool eventFilter (QObject* const pObject,
                    QEvent* const pEvent) override
  {
    qDebug() << "Event: " << pEvent->type();
    if(pEvent->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
      QKeyEvent* const pKeyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(pEvent);
      qDebug() << "Key event: " << pKeyEvent->key();
    }
    return false; //QObject::eventFilter(pObject, pEvent);
  }
};


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication application(argc, argv);
  Widget widget;
  widget.show();
  return application.exec();
}
```

Comment: What you really want is a timer, in combination with a platform-specific way to query the last user input. `QTimer` solves the former, in a platform-agnostic way. The latter doesn't have a platform-agnostic implementation. On Windows you'd call [GetLastInputInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getlastinputinfo). On Linux you'd call any single one of the myriad of different implementations available. There is no standard API on Linux for this.

Comment: You are welcome to post an answer of your own. Your question should remain strictly a question, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have written minimal working code for the 3 platforms below. Using Qt is optional.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<chrono>

struct Activity
{
  Activity ();
};

// You may need to put Qt equivalent part here; The core logic is after main()
#include<QGuiApplication>
int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{  // Qt specific; but it can be anything here
  QGuiApplication application(argc, argv);
  Activity activity;
  return application.exec();
}

#ifdef __linux__  // add in .pro file "linux: QT += x11extras" and "linux: LIBS += -lX11 -lXtst"
#include<X11/Xlib.h>
#include<X11/extensions/record.h>

#define CHECK(EVENT) if(*pDatum == EVENT) std::cout << #EVENT
void Handle (XPointer, XRecordInterceptData *pRecord)
{
  using XRecordDatum = char;
  std::cout << pRecord->category << "---" << pRecord->data;
  if(auto* const pDatum = reinterpret_cast<XRecordDatum*>(pRecord->data))
  { CHECK(KeyPress); else CHECK(KeyRelease); else CHECK(ButtonPress); else CHECK(ButtonRelease); }
  ::XRecordFreeData(pRecord);
}

Activity::Activity ()
{
  if(auto* const pDisplay = XOpenDisplay(nullptr))
  {
    XRecordClientSpec clients = XRecordAllClients;
    auto* pRange = ::XRecordAllocRange();
    pRange->device_events = XRecordRange8{KeyPress, ButtonRelease};
    auto context = ::XRecordCreateContext(pDisplay, 0, &clients, 1, &pRange, 1);
    ::XRecordEnableContextAsync(pDisplay, context, Handle, nullptr); // use with/without `...Async()`

    //  ::XRecordProcessReplies(pDisplay);
    ::XFlush(pDisplay);
    ::XSync(pDisplay, true);
  }
// Use below functions by putting variables in global scope to stop capturing
// Also refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69711608/why-xrecorddisablecontext-is-not-working
// ::XRecordDisableContext(pDisplay, context);
//  ::XRecordFreeContext(pDisplay, context);
//  ::XFree(pRange);
}
#endif

#ifdef WIN32
#include<Windows.h> // add in .pro file "win32: LIBS += -luser32"

HHOOK sHookKeyboard, sHookMouse;
Activity::Activity ()
{
    sHookKeyboard = ::SetWindowsHookExA(WH_KEYBOARD_LL,
                     [] (int i, WPARAM w, LPARAM l)
                     { std::cout << i << w << l; return ::CallNextHookEx(sHookKeyboard, i, w, l); },
                                        0, 0);
    sHookMouse = ::SetWindowsHookExA(WH_MOUSE_LL,
                     [] (int i, WPARAM w, LPARAM l)
                     { std::cout << i << w << l; return ::CallNextHookEx(sHookMouse, i, w, l); },
                                        0, 0);
}
#endif

#ifdef __APPLE__ // add in .pro file "mac: LIBS += -framework ApplicationServices"
#include<ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>
// Add binary (& if you are it via running Qt, then that too) into the "privacy" settings of the ...
// ... Mac system; System Preferences > Privacy settings; Without this the code will not work

// https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/109283
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556278/cgeventtapcreates-watching-keyboard-input-in-cocoa
Activity::Activity ()
{
  CGEventMask mask = CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventKeyDown) | CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventScrollWheel) |
                     CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventLeftMouseDown) | CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventRightMouseDown);
  auto eventTap = CGEventTapCreate(kCGSessionEventTap, kCGHeadInsertEventTap,
                                   kCGEventTapOptionDefault, mask,
                       [] (CGEventTapProxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef event, void*)
                       { std::cout << "captured: " << type; return event; }, this);
  if(eventTap == nullptr)
    return;

  CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),
                     CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, eventTap, 0),
                     kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
  // Enable the event tap.
  CGEventTapEnable(eventTap, true);
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

you need system-wide mouse hook and keyb hook. It should be in stand-alone `dll` which is registered in windows. Then you should add it to qt . use installnativeeventfilter and within the filter where you can use plain windows C code (from msvc) do `SetWindowsHookEx()` twice. Ofc hook stuff from dll should be visible in this filter module. All in all your chances to do it aren't that much . i think you agree with me haha

forget about platform-independent something

some tips:
for hook's callback function use `CALLBACK` type
dll should be placed in windows\system or so. In windows 7 it's enough
my bet is that you can do `#pragma comment(lib, <hook_lib>)` in native filter's `.cpp` . i mean `.lib` you'll have after making `.dll`
use `.def` for export.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-def-files?view=msvc-160

Comment: Can you please give a code example? Need this solution for all the 3 platforms.

Comment: for native filter you can look here https://github.com/alexeyneu/bitcoin/blob/bbd5aa3e36cf303779d888764e1ebb3bd2242a4a/src/qt/winshutdownmonitor.cpp

Comment: i dont have sources for app / dll with hooks. app i've written on that - i didn't test it past windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Have written minimal code for the 3 platforms with below concerns:

- Linux: Very simplistic. It certainly captures <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd> etc special keys and mouse clicks. The other keyboard inputs are captures sometimes and sometimes they don't. It's inconsistent. If use `XGrabKeyboard()` API, then all the keys are captured. However I don't know how to pass on those keys to the visible application as it is.
- Windows: Works fine & straightforward!
- Mac OSX: Doesn't work yet. There might be something missing. I will update, if I find something.

---

```
#include<QAbstractEventDispatcher>
#include<QAbstractNativeEventFilter>
#include<QGuiApplication>
#include<QDebug>

struct EventFilter : QAbstractNativeEventFilter
{
  EventFilter ();
  bool nativeEventFilter (const QByteArray& eventType, void* pMessage, long*) override;
};

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QGuiApplication application(argc, argv);
  EventFilter m_Filter;
  return application.exec();
}

#ifdef __linux__  // add in .pro file "linux: QT += x11extras" and "linux: LIBS += -lX11"
#include<QX11Info>

EventFilter::EventFilter () { qApp->eventDispatcher()->installNativeEventFilter(this); }

bool EventFilter::nativeEventFilter (const QByteArray& eventType, void* pMessage, long*)
{
  auto* const pEvent = static_cast<xcb_generic_event_t*>(pMessage);
  switch(pEvent->response_type)
  {
  case 28: case 37:        qDebug() << eventType << ": Keypress (special)" << pEvent->response_type; break;
  case 2: case 3: case 35: qDebug() << eventType << ": Keypress (general)"  << pEvent->response_type; break;
  case 85:                 qDebug() << eventType << ": Mouse Click"; break;
  default:                 qDebug() << eventType << ": <others> " << pEvent->response_type; break;
  }
  return false;
}
#endif

#ifdef WIN32
#include<Windows.h> // add in .pro file "win32: LIBS += -luser32"

HHOOK sHookKeyboard, sHookMouse;
EventFilter::EventFilter ()
{
    sHookKeyboard = ::SetWindowsHookExA(WH_KEYBOARD_LL,
                     [] (int i, WPARAM w, LPARAM l)
                     { qDebug() << i << w << l; return ::CallNextHookEx(sHookKeyboard, i, w, l); },
                                        0, 0);
    sHookMouse = ::SetWindowsHookExA(WH_MOUSE_LL,
                     [] (int i, WPARAM w, LPARAM l)
                     { qDebug() << i << w << l; return ::CallNextHookEx(sHookMouse, i, w, l); },
                                        0, 0);
}
bool nativeEventFilter (const QByteArray& eventType, void* pMessage, long*) {}
#endif

#ifdef __APPLE__ // add in .pro file "mac: LIBS += -framework Carbon"
#include<Carbon/Carbon.h>  // give required permission to the binary from "Application" settings

OSStatus HandleKeyboard (EventHandlerCallRef nextHandler, EventRef event, void* data)
{ qDebug() << "KeyPress event raised: "; return noErr; }
OSStatus HandleMouse (EventHandlerCallRef nextHandler, EventRef event, void* data)
{ qDebug() << "MouseClick event raised: "; return noErr; }

EventFilter::EventFilter ()
{
  EventTypeSpec eventKeyPress;
  eventKeyPress.eventClass = kEventClassKeyboard;
  eventKeyPress.eventKind = kEventRawKeyDown;
  InstallApplicationEventHandler(HandleKeyboard, 1, &eventKeyPress, nullptr, nullptr);

  EventTypeSpec eventMouseClick;
  eventMouseClick.eventClass = kEventClassMouse;
  eventMouseClick.eventKind = kEventMouseDown;
  InstallApplicationEventHandler(HandleMouse, 1, &eventMouseClick, nullptr, nullptr);
}
bool nativeEventFilter (const QByteArray& eventType, void* pMessage, long*) {}
#endif
```

Comment: You installed an application filter which is not going to work when the application is minimized then loses focus.