# Why XRecordDisableContext() is not working?

Tags: c++, linux, event-handling, x11, xorg

```
void Callback (XPointer, XRecordInterceptData *pRecord) { std::cout << "my logs\n"; }

int main ()
{
  if(auto* const pDisplay = XOpenDisplay(nullptr))
  {
    XRecordClientSpec clients = XRecordAllClients;
    auto* pRange = ::XRecordAllocRange();
    pRange->device_events = XRecordRange8{KeyPress, ButtonRelease};
    auto context = ::XRecordCreateContext(pDisplay, 0, &clients, 1, &pRange, 1);
    ::XRecordEnableContextAsync(pDisplay, context, Callback, nullptr); // use with/without `...Async()`

    ::XRecordDisableContext(pDisplay, context);
    ::XRecordFreeContext(pDisplay, context);
    ::XFree(pRange);

    ::XFlush(pDisplay);
    ::XSync(pDisplay, true);
  }
}
```

I am noticing that even after `XRecordDisableContext()`, the `Callback()` continues to be invoked.
How can we disable the recording, so that the callback isn't invoked anymore?

**Note**:

- Have taken example from [this site](https://cpp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/XRecordEnableContext/cpp-xrecordenablecontext-function-examples.html).
- Don't know how to use `XRecordEnableContext()`, so using `XRecordEnableContextAsync()`. Is that the source of problem?

Comment: is it possibly because you need to do an XSync?

Comment: @user253751, already doing an `XSync()` in the end of the code. Isn't that correct?

Comment: seems like you might get callbacks that were sent by the server before it received the call to XRecordDisableContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to move below statement into the `Callback()` or some equivalent other thread. For testing purpose, I changed the code as below where after few event raised, I disable from the `Callback()` and it works.

```
::Display* pDisplay;
XRecordRange* pRange;
XRecordContext context;

#define CHECK(EVENT) if(*pDatum == EVENT) qDebug() << #EVENT
void Handle (XPointer, XRecordInterceptData *pRecord)
{
  std::cout << "my logs\n";
  static int i = 0;
  if(++i < 10)
    return;
  ::XRecordDisableContext(pDisplay, context);
  ::XRecordFreeContext(pDisplay, context);
  ::XFree(pRange);

  ::XFlush(pDisplay);
  ::XSync(pDisplay, true);
}
// other code same, except 3 variables are global and "Free"-up functions are not required
```